# MySQL "join as"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables joined together:

[image: table_diagram]

the `book_types_purchased` is `ENUM('paperback','hardcover')`. I want to get this type of row returned:

```
book_title | paperback_date_purchased | hardcover_date_purchased
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

---

## UPDATE

Here is the answer from below with matching table names and left joins instead:

```
SELECT title,
  paperback.date_purchased AS paperback_date_purchased,
  hardcover.date_purchased AS hardcover_date_purchased

FROM book_projects

LEFT JOIN book_types_purchased AS paperback 
  ON paperback.book_project_id = book_projects.id
  AND paperback.type = 'paperback'

LEFT JOIN book_types_purchased AS hardcover 
  ON hardcover.book_project_id = book_projects.id
  AND hardcover.type = 'hardcover'
```

Comment: Just as an aside: you might want to eventually rethink the "`ENUM`" choice for the `book_types_purchased`.  For example, what if you need to add digital or ebook "book types" in the future?  [Here are a few more reasons](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)...

Comment: @summea thanks for the article, good read. Thanks to that I have changed all ENUM fields in a schema I'm working on to join with a related table instead.

Comment: Sorry for the extra work... but hopefully it helps you in the long run...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the `book_types_purchased` table twice.  One for each type.

```
SELECT title,
  paperback.date_purchased AS paperback_date_purchased,
  hardcover.date_purchased AS hardcover_date_purchased

FROM book_projects

JOIN date_purchased AS paperback ON paperback.book_project_id = book_projects.id
  AND paperback.type = 'paperback'

JOIN date_purchased AS hardcover ON hardcover.book_project_id = book_projects.id
  AND hardcover.type = 'hardcover'
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified this to LEFT JOIN so it would return NULL if a related paperback or hardcover wasn't found.